# get constructor parameters from activation context

Tags: c#, ninject

Assuming I want to have instances created by a ProxyFactory, I need to be able to pass this factory a list of constructor parameters.

```
public class Foo : ViewModelBase
{
    public Bar MyBar { get; private set; }

    [Inject]
    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        MyBar = bar;
    }
}
```

Here's my current Module, which needs to be extended to pass the dependencies as they would be resolved by ninject into the ProxyFactory

```
public class InjectionModuleForConstructorArgsTest : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ViewModelProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ViewModelProxyFactory();
        Bind<Foo>().ToMethod(
        ctx =>
        {
            return proxyFactory.CreateViewModelProxy<Foo>();
        });
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is an automation of the following:

```
Bind<Foo>().ToMethod(
ctx =>
{
    return proxyFactory.CreateViewModelProxy<Foo>(Kernel.Get<Bar>());
});
```

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: The answer is either Ninject.Extensions.Factory or an edit explaining why that's not enough

Comment: Well, actually it **is** a solution I can live with (I use it already), but I'd like to get a grasp on the ActivationContext and hoped to find a more generic approach...I will check out that Factory Extension you mentioned (+1 for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation I'd reccomend to implement the `ViewModelProxyFactory` as a `Provider<Foo>` and inject the `Bar` into the constructor of the [provider](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context)

```
public class ViewModelProxyFactory<T> : Provider<T>
{
    public ViewModelProxyFactory(Bar bar) { this.bar = bar; }

    public T CreateInstance(IContext ctx)
    {
        return putYourFactoryCodeHere
    }
}

Bind<Foo>().ToProvider<ViewModelProxyFactory<Foo>>();
```

Comment: thanks Remo, this sounds nice. I'll give it a go and return here later!

Comment: Now that I took a closer look, I don't think this is what I need. The ProxyFactory Is supposed to add Change Notification facility to whatever class is thrown into it. This Factory approach means I have to create one Factory per class I want to decorate. I need a generic approach. Thanks, anyway and +1 for pointing me to this!

Comment: In that case you should explain more in detail what you are doing in that factory.

Comment: In that factory, I use Castle to generate A `ClassProxy` and add an interceptor that handles ChangeNotification whenever a setter on a property is called. I would like to add support for non-parameterless constructors (and Castle does support that, I just need to get them there)

Comment: Have a look at the Interception extension. It adds support to create such proxies for any type.